# Why wouldn't SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource pull back efficiently to begin with

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why wouldn't `SqlDataSource` or `ObjectDataSource` pull back efficiently to begin with?

For example, say we're retrieving records for `Northwind` customers. There's 91 customers. If you use `SqlDataSource` or `ObjectDataSource`, why wouldn't it pull back just 10 at a time (by default) to begin with instead of all 91 records?

Wouldn't that promote better design?

Comment: The most efficient quantity retrieved depends upon the context of your application. For example, you might want just 10 records for a grid, but still need 91 for a drop-down.

Comment: How do you define *the first 10 rows* for every possible table on this planet? *The first 10* always implies an **ordering** - so you cannot possibly do this for all tables. What if you want 15? 20? 25? How do you handle all of this?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that part can be configurable like it is now

Answer (score 1):

Use your own controls, make method to work with database, and select all records what you need, as you need, using your own conditions. SqlDataSource is for general cases, not a private case.